# Using different files for different hosts

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible (with Ansible Tower) and want to create a task which runs a test.

I have a properties file for (SoapUI tests) which is of the form key=value. The value will change according to the host that the test is running on.

Although there is a way to specify different variables per host there does not seem to be a way to specify different files for different hosts.

The best way there seems to be (to my knowledge) is to create a template (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) instead of the properties file and populate the template values using host variables. Is there an alternative or better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply set the file path to be a variable.

So if you have a task that is copying a file to the box that looks like:

```
- name: Copy properties file to box
  copy:
    src: path/to/file
    dest: path/to/dest
```

You could simply change this to be:

```
- name: Copy properties file to box
  copy:
    src: "{{ properties_file }}"
    dest: path/to/dest
```

And then you simply need to set your `properties_file` variable for the appropriate environment group or host like so:

group_vars/dev:

```
properties_file: path/to/dev/file
```

group_vars/prod:

```
properties_file: path/to/prod/file
```